# JEST: how to stub a method which is been called in constructor of the class

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs, babeljs

This how a example looks like:

```
export class ABC {
  constructor() {
    this.method1();
  }

  method1() {
    console.log();
  }
}
```

Assume that there are some calls to external methods in `method1` which are stopping the code to go forward. I don't want to go inside the `method1`.

Now the problem is when I do this:

```
describe('test cases!', () => {
  let abc: ABC;
  beforeEach(() => {
    spyOn(abc, 'method1').and.stub();
    abc = new ABC();
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });
});
```

It's throwing error.

After the class initialisation I can't put the `spyOn`.
Any idea guys?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 6):

`method1` exists on `ABC.prototype` and you can spy on it and replace the implementation before constructing a new instance of `ABC`:

```js
class ABC {
  constructor() {
    this.method1();
  }
  method1() {
    throw new Error('should not get here');
  }
}

test('ABC', () => {
  const spy = jest.spyOn(ABC.prototype, 'method1');  // spy on the method of the prototype
  spy.mockImplementation(() => {});  // replace the implementation
  const abc = new ABC();  // no error
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();  // SUCCESS
})
```

Answer (score 3):

To build upon @brian-lives-outdoors answer, I use the following:

```
describe('test cases!', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    ABC.prototype.abc = jest.fn((data) => { result: 'some mock here', data)
    abc = new ABC();
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    ABC.prototype.abc.mockRestore()
  })
});
```