# How to properly call an init function in a ts class

Tags: javascript, mocking, jestjs

I'm writing some tests for a class.  In my tests if I don't call `browserViewPreload.init()` the test fails, but when I do call `browserViewPreload.init()` it passes.

Why should I need to explicitly call `browserViewPreload.init()` in the test when I've already done it in my beforeEach block?

```
//myFile.ts
export default class BrowserViewPreload {
    constructor(){
       this.init();
    }
     attachMouse(){
      console.log('attaching mouse')
    }

    init(){
      return document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', this.attachMouse)
    }

  }

//myFile.spec.ts
import BrowserViewPreload from './browserViewPreload'
function bootStrapComponent() {
    return new BrowserViewPreload(); 
};
describe('BrowserViewPreload Class', () => {
    var browserViewPreload;
    let initSpy
    let docspy
    let mouseSpy
    beforeEach(()=>{

        browserViewPreload = bootStrapComponent(); 
        initSpy = jest.spyOn(browserViewPreload, 'init')
        docspy = jest.spyOn(document, 'addEventListener')

    })
    it('should report name', () => {
        //browserViewPreload.init(); not including this makes the tests fail.  Why do I need to make the call here when I've already done so in the beforeEach
        expect(initSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(docspy).toHaveBeenCalled();
        document.dispatchEvent(new Event('DOMContentLoaded'));
        expect(mouseSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's because you are creating BrowserViewPreload object before attaching the initSpy to it.

Comment: but I can't do the opposite because browserViewPreload isn't defined yet to add the spy onto.

Comment: Maybe this thread can help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54217276/jest-how-to-stub-a-method-which-is-been-called-in-constructor-of-the-class